# How can I change the sprite's color with a hex color value

Tags: java, libgdx

i am trying to set the color of a sprite with a hex color code.
But it's not working...

```
Sprite bricks;
bricks = new Sprite(new Texture("strip.png"));
bricks.getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
batch.begin();
bricks.draw(batch);
batch.end();
```

in another funcion

```
bricks.setColor(36/255f, 48/255f, 209/255f, 0.7f);//set color hex code
```

but the sprite color is not changing

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting

Comment: You need to show more context around your code. The sprite.setColor method works perfectly fine for me the way you wrote it. Is that first block of code literally what you have in your render method? Because if it is, then your problem is that you are shadowing the `bricks` member variable in your render method, so you are not drawing the sprite whose color you change elsewhere, but instead are drawing a brand new sprite you just created on every frame.

Comment: bricks.setColor() is not under render() method. it is under another method and not called by render method;